# is the square of an integrable random variable always integrable

Tags: probability

Is the square of an integrable random variable always integrable? Is there a proof/counterxample? I'm having trouble finding some counter-examples as the usual distributions always have a well-defined variance.

Comment: There are easy counterexamples on $[0,1]$ with Leb. measure.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks I think that works.